# How to map through the array to generate dynamic form based on api response?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am using React.js. I want to create a dynamic form based on some api response. Below are the conditions for creation of the form.

1.Form fields must be generated based on values from table1 and table2 key from entityTable array. sometime table1 and table2 key may contain multiple values. In that case I need to split the values based on comma(,) and consider them individual values.

2. Now, I need to compare those values received from table1 and table2 key with the keys of recievedData object. If there is match then I need to generate form field with initialValue of corresponding key's value.
3. The form field must be disabled based on the key values of table1_edit and table2_edit from entityTable array. If value is 0, the form field must be disabled.

Please visit the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-wood-v7vsn) link for the code.

What I have done so far

```
class Todo extends Component {

  render() {

    // Here is the API response

    const data = {
      recievedData: {
        pan_number: "3213265",
        gender: "M",
        last_name: "45645",
        pan_status: "VALID",
        middle_name: "null",
        rece_pan_num: "435353",
        first_name: "464",
        sent_pan_num: "546546",
        pan_name: "some name",
        pan_holder_title: "null"
      },
      questions: [],
      entityTable: [
        {
          id: 1,
          table1: "pan_number",
          table2: "sent_pan_num,rece_pan_num,pan_status",
          table1_edit: "1",
          table2_edit: "0"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          table1: "pan_name,first_name",
          table2: "middle_name,last_name",
          table1_edit: "1",
          table2_edit: "0"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          table1: "gender",
          table2: "pan_holder_title",
          table1_edit: "1",
          table2_edit: "0"
        }
      ]
    };

    const mainArray = [];

    const givenData =
      data.entityTable &&
      data.entityTable.map(item => {
        if (item.table1.includes(",")) {
          let newArray = item.table1.split(",");
          let itemProp = item.table1_edit;
          mainArray.push({ table_one: newArray, itemProp: itemProp });
        } else {
          if (item.table1 === "" || item.table1 === null) {
            return null;
          } else {
            let newArray = item.table1;
            let itemProp = item.table1_edit;
            mainArray.push({ table_one: newArray, itemProp: itemProp });
          }
        }

        if (item.table2.includes(",")) {
          let newArray = item.table2.split(",");
          let itemProp = item.table2_edit;
          mainArray.push({ table_two: newArray, itemProp: itemProp });
        } else {
          if (item.table2 === "" || item.table2 === null) {
            return null;
          } else {
            let newArray = item.table2;
            let itemProp = item.table2_edit;
            mainArray.push({ table_two: newArray, itemProp: itemProp });
          }
        }
        return mainArray;
      });
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          {Object.keys(data.recievedData).map((selec, index) => {


            // Here how do I need to compare the values from givenData to check the match?

            return <input placeholder={data.recievedData[selec]} />;
          })}
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

First, I map through the entityTable array and pushed the required value to an array. Now I stuck in the comparison that need to be done with recievedData object. How do I have to loop through the givenData array to check the match?

Comment: You're doing ALL of the logic in the `render` function, which doesn't seem ideal to me. If you have the data to start with, whether it's based on props or something else, you should either do it in the constructor or in the `componentDidMount` function

Comment: Secondly, if you want to conditionally render stuff, you should use a function on the class that returns a component conditionally. I'll post an example answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using the exact data structures you need because I don't really want to have to figure out exactly everything you need to do, I just wanted to show you how you might conditionally render one element based on if it matches something from another array:

```
class Todo extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            recievedData: [{
                id: 2,
                editable: false,
                value: 'x'
            }, {
                id: 3,
                editable: true,
                value: 'm'
            }],
            givenData: [{
                id: 3,
                value: 'r'
            }]
        };

        this.renderItem = this.renderItem.bind(this);
    }

    renderItem(data, index) {
        const name = `item_${index}`;
        const matchingData = this.state.givenData.find(item => item.id === data.id);

        const readOnly = !data.editable;

        if (matchingData) {
            return <input name={name} type="text" readOnly={readOnly} defaultValue={matchingData.value}/>
        } else {
            return <input name={name} type="text" readOnly={readOnly} defaultValue={data.value}/>
        }
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <form>
                    {Object.keys(this.state.recievedData).map((selec, index) => {
                        // Here how do I need to compare the values from givenData to check the match?
                        return this.renderItem(selec, index);
                    })}
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

As you can see, you can use a function inside the class to return a component. Use this function inside your `.map` function. You'll probably want the `inputs` to have a key a well, probably based on the id